# Weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS when initialising object

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash

I have a weird EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash, I'm trying to initialise an object by using singleton like this :

```
@objc final class Toto: XSuperClass {

    /// Singleton
    @objc static var instance = Toto()


    /// Hide the creator to force using singleton
    @objc private init() {
        print("Initializer is called !")
        super.init(
            "xyz",
            serverHost: "",
            serverPath: ""
        )
    }

    @objc func update() {
        ...
    }
```

The XSuperClass extends from NSObject and contained in a pod.

In Appdelegate :

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [[Toto instance] update];
}
```

**Sometimes** it crashes at : `@objc static var instance = Toto() Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9)`

The thread 1 contains :

```
#11 0x0000000105a20004 in Toto.instance.unsafeMutableAddressor at /Users/.../Toto.swift
#10 0x00000001076196d9 in swift_once ()
#8  0x0000000107e5ad48 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#7  0x0000000105a1ff90 in globalinit_33_0DC663E05309E94BD36536F7E931D58A_func0 at /Users/../Toto.swift
#6  0x0000000105a21028 in type metadata accessor for Toto ()
#0  0x0000000107602737 in swift_checkMetadataState ()
```

The XSuperClass :

```
/** This class is the base class that handles ... */
@objc open class XSuperClass: NSObject {

...

/// Main initializer
    public init(_ feature: String,
                ... dependencies that all have default values,
                serverHost: String?,
                serverPath: String?
    ) {
        self.feature = feature
        ...
        self.serverHost = serverHost
        self.serverPath = serverPath
    }
```

It seems that I'm trying to initialise a released object in memory, but I can't figure out how to fix this, I spent a lot of time investigating the problem with no luck, any ideas please ?

[EDIT]
THIS CRASH OCCURS ONLY ON IOS 13

Comment: Is the source code of the real superclass publicly available. Is it an Objective C class cluster?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It's a swift class, I edited the question.

Comment: Why do you need all the ```@objc``` ?

Comment: for Toto's ```init()```, the ```@objc``` is useless, for others we have to expose all the methods to be used in objective c classes.